# Django not serving some static files

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I'm facing quite a strange issue with Django, my `STATIC_URL` is `/static/` and I've got an app installed using `pip` as `-e git+git://github.com/foo/bar.git#egg=bar` which loads it into the virtualenv src folder.

Now, I'm trying to GET a static file related to this app as `/static/bar/js/something.js` and the src folder does have a `bar/bar/static/bar/js/something.js` file. Even if I `findstatic` `bar/js/something.js` it gives me a valid path to the file. However when I access it using the browser, I'm 301'd to `/static/bar/js/something.js/` which 404s.

Why would this be happening?

Even poking around with `staticfiles` app, I was able to see that it recognizes my app as installed and that its `static` folder exists. However somehow the static files aren't being served.

Comment: Are you in development? Have you set up URLs so that the test server will server the files for you? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development

Comment: What's in your STATICFILES_DIRS in settings.py ?

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony Can you please post this as an answer so I can mark it as correct? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you have [set up the django development server to actually server the static files for you](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development).

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
# ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this urlpattern:

```
 url( r'(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': '/path/to/file/'}),
```

Comment: I know I can do that, but considering `virtualenv` `/path/to/file/` will change on different machines/environments.

Comment: I use a config for that issue: `settings['INSTALL_ROOT']`.